# How to make tooltips always visible in Doughnut chart?

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, ng2-charts

This is my current chart [image]

My expected result.
I want to display the tooltip on the chart fields at all times.

[image]

I tried adding this code to the options.

```
doughnutChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
      legend:{
        display:true,
        position:'bottom'
      },

      tooltips: {
        enabled: true,
        callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
            var datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
            return label  + ' '+ datasetLabel + '%';

          }
        }
      }

  };
```